# how make my code run by `setInterval` without spam the user

Tags: javascript

i'm working on a "reminder" app & i guess i finished it but my problem about how to make the code run or keep seeing numbers to when `currentHour` matches the `medicTime` the alarm start so i tried `setInterval` & `setTimeout` but both not work well with me (setTimeout not work, i must reload page & setInterval keep spamming) so i want a way to make the code see data inside page & run the alarm without spam, the app *maybe* will remind users every hour so yeah & at same time i want `setInterval` in low number in case the page closed by mistake

```
// It's my dumb database so yeah do not worry about it
config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBZHH97LQ42n7j0fBjKR7LCLXkeDq-L7iw",
  authDomain: "pro-core-169202.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://pro-core-169202.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "pro-core-169202",
  storageBucket: "pro-core-169202.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "58388231689"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

let dataRef = firebase.database().ref("data");

dataRef.on("child_added", snap => {
  let name = snap.child("name").val();
  let medicName = snap.child("medicName").val();
  let medicTime = snap.child("medicTime").val();
  let notes = snap.child("notes").val();

  $("#dataShow").append("<tr><td>" + "Name: " + name + "</td><td>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;" + " Medic Name: " + medicName + "</td><td>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;" + " Medic Time: " + medicTime + "</td><td>" + "&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;&nbsp;" + " Notes: " + notes + "<br>");

  let date = new Date();
  let currentHour = date.getHours();

  setTimeout(function () {
    if (medicTime == currentHour) {
      alert("it's " + medicName + " Time!" + "(It's " + medicTime + " Time!)");
    }
  }, 1)
})

let date = new Date();
  let currentHour = date.getHours();

  console.log(currentHour);
```

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where you would want to check whether or not a timer hits every millisecond. Perhaps when you poll the database you would want to check the amount of time between the current time and the alert, then if it's greater or equal throw up a dialog until it's dismissed. You could use a timeout to supplement this, but I wouldn't bother setting one unless it's within a certain range since people are prone to navigate away, etc.

Comment: You need to understand more about what you're doing. Look up what `setTimeout` and `alert` do, and then you'll understand why you're getting a popup every millisecond.

Comment: yeah problem in that, if i used setInterval for like notify every hour & page closed the code will not work & if i used setTimeout the code will run when i refresh page so i need something in betweent

Answer (score 0):

Dates should be checked inside setTimeout callback:

```
  setTimeout(function () {
    let date = new Date();
    let currentHour = date.getHours();
    if (medicTime == currentHour) {
      alert("it's " + medicName + " Time!" + "(It's " + medicTime + " Time!)");
    }
  }, 1)
```

## Mock code for localstorage support

```js
// This will not work in snippet because sandboxing
$('#test').click(
  () => localStorage.setItem('start', new Date().getTime()) // Time in ms from 1 Jan 1970
)

checkTime = () => {
  //if no date set in localstorage...
  if(!localStorage.getItem('start')) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
  const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  const startTime = localStorage.getItem('start');
  if(currentTime - startTime > 60000){ // if 60s are passed
      clearInterval(myInterval); // Unregister interval
      alert('Timeout, 60 seconds!');
  }
}

// Run the check every seconds
const myInterval = setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: yeah problem in that, if i used setInterval for like notify every hour & page closed the code will not work & if i used setTimeout the code will run when i refresh page so i need something in betweent

Comment: Ok got it. save start time in local storage, when page load compare current Date() with Date() in localstorage, so you can determine the timing also on page close.

Comment: interesting, more info ? @Mosè Raguzzini